# The right way of mapping 0, j, k, ^, $ to g0, gj, gk, g^, g$ when wrap is set

Tags: key-bindings, autocmd, wrapping

First, I'm not sure just mapping `j` to `gj` always is a good idea, because, for instance, I don't want `j` to behave as `gj` when `wrap` is off and the line is longer than the screen.

How can I make <kbd>0</kbd>, <kbd>j</kbd>, <kbd>k</kbd>, <kbd>^</kbd>, <kbd>$</kbd> behave like <kbd>g0</kbd>, <kbd>gj</kbd>, <kbd>gk</kbd>, <kbd>g^</kbd>, <kbd>g$</kbd> when `wrap` is set? What is the proper way to do so?

I thought a good starting point could be

```
function! s:setDisplayLinesMovementWhenWrapOn()
  if &wrap
    nnoremap <buffer> j gj
    nnoremap <buffer> k gk
    nnoremap <buffer> 0 g0
    nnoremap <buffer> ^ g^
    nnoremap <buffer> $ g$
  else
    nunmap <buffer> j
    nunmap <buffer> k
    nunmap <buffer> 0
    nunmap <buffer> ^
    nunmap <buffer> $
  endif
endfunction

augroup DisplayLinesMovementWhenWrapOn
  autocmd!
  autocmd OptionSet wrap call s:setDisplayLinesMovementWhenWrapOn()
augroup END
```

But probably I also need another `autocmd` to call `s:setDisplayLinesMovementWhenWrapOn` when a buffer is read? Or a file? Or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use *expression mappings* for cases like this; normally a Vim mapping just sends the keys on the right-hand-side of a `:map` command straight to Vim, but with expression mappings it's interpreted as a VimScript expression, and the resulting value is used. You can use this to check if `wrap` is set.

```
nnoremap <expr> j &wrap ? 'gj' : 'j'
```

As far as I know and as I read the docs, `gj` (and related) already behave identical to `j` when wrapping is off, so I'm not sure if this is a very useful mapping as such, but this is the general strategy to make mappings behave different depending on which settings you have enabled/disabled.

---

Bonus tip: you can also use `:execute` to create mappings, since all of these are so similar. For example:

```
for k in 'jk0^$'
    exe printf("nnoremap <expr> %s &wrap ? 'g%s' : '%s'", k, k, k)
endfor
```

Comment: Yes, I think `gj` behaves like `j` when `wrap` is off; however, `g0` and `g$` have different effects depending on whether `wrap` is on or off, but in neither case they behave as `0` and `$`.

Comment: Ah right @Enlico; I just checked the docs for `gj` and assumed that would apply to all the `g*` movement commands.

Comment: As a tip for the readers, I ended up using `&wrap && v:count == 0` as the discriminating condition for `j` and `k`, the reason being that since I use `relativenumber`, when I put a count for `j` and `k` I most likely don't want to move across a single wrapped line (even if I wanted, I wouldn't have a way to know what the count should be other than counting, so it's just more practical to hit `j`/`k` repeatedly).